# Limiting HTTPS to specific application routes

Tags: ssl, apache2

I have an application that uses routing rules to define actions for users, and specific entity types. Is it possible to create a specific set of rules for Apache's SSL implementation to permit specific paths on the site to use HTTPS, with other routing rules using HTTP? The current routing rules are a basic argument reformat:

```
<Directory "/var/www/exampleapp/public/">
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</Directory>
```

All application behavior is being served on a VirtualHost on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few ways to do this, one way is given below.
Assuming all your requests are arriving on https, you can do the following :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uri1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uri2 [NC]
..
..
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

In this case, you are listing the uri's that you need on https and are redirecting the remaining to http
You can always switch it around